# Could not find a part of path when using ImageBrush

Tags: wpf

I get that error if i try to run my "application". In fact that's an empty window with background.

```
<Window x:Class="NWN_Tsuki.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="831" Width="875">
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush Stretch="None" ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Book.png" />
</Window.Background>
<Grid/>
</Window>
```

That's all my app. And i get error. If i set absolute path to image - all working fine.

I tried to google, i searched same topics here and tried to do what worked for others - there are no progress. Just one window. Just one background image in resourses added through wizard.

Visual Studio 2013, Windows 7 Ultimate x64

Comment: What is the exact error text? Is it compilation or runtime error? And what happens if you change Imagesource in property window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried adding an image thru a wizard, what I do is create a "Resources" folder in my project. Then I add the image in said folder. Set the property of the image to Copy Always or Copy If New.  Then do:

```
<ImageBrush Stretch="None" ImageSource="../Resources/Book.png" />
```

If anything, Book.png is just not getting copied.

EDIT: **IMPORTANT** Also make sure to change the Book.png's **Build Action** to **Resource**

Comment: Answer Updated. I used an Image instead of ImageBrush. I'm not sure why but there's a difference between them as written by Sacha Barber http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37341/A-Moan-About-ImageBrush-In-WPF  .

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you can just write ImageSource="Resources/Book.png" and it will work.

Second, if you want with "pack://", you suppose to write it ImageSource="pack://**application**:,,,/Resources/Book.png"

Yet another way - ImageSource="ProjectName;component/Resources/Book.png" where ProjectName is the name of the project where you keep you picture.
You can even concatenate all this if you need ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/ProjectName;component/Resources/Book.png"

Comment: ImageSource="Resources/Book.png" same error; ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Recources/Book.png" same error;  ImageSource="ProjectName;component/Recources/Book.png" Blend doesnt support this file format. And yes im SURE that files is in ProjectName/Resources/

Comment: Maybe im suffer in vain? Im only need a single-file application in result and with absolute path image will still be baked in? Just new to WPF.

Comment: @Kodek Please, ensure in properties of this resource file that build action = resource.

Comment: Hmm. ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Recources/Book.png"  - i had a typo here. It's not ReCourses, it's reSources. It It produces the same error, maybe you have a typo somewhere, too?

Comment: Well, im not just copy-pasted =) And yes, still error. In topics with similar problem advise to do some non-scietific actions to re-name files and such... doesnt help to me. Also some man said that this error is "fake error" and application compile successfully and work perfectly even with it. But it bugging me. May be that bug of VS2013 or something?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this. It turned out, the .png was corrupted. When I navigated to the folder in File Explorer, I saw the following

[image]

I think the mkelem is something to do with our source control, so maybe it was that which corrupted it, regardless, this is why some people may get this error message.